# Как дождаться запуска БД и выполнить команды?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Есть проект из 2х контейнеров. На одном стоит БД `mysql`, на другом развернуто приложение. Как можно составить `Dockerfile` или `docker-compose.yml`, чтобы при сборке образа приложения или запуске контейнера дожидался полный старт БД, и только потом запускался сервис полностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске сервиса можно запустить `bash`-script, для этого нужно создать файл с расширением `sh` например `entrypoint.sh` и в нем запускать команду `sleep`, после нее можно указать остальные команды для запуска вашего сервиса.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 15

<другие команды>
```

Далее, в `docker-compose.yml` в вашем сервисе нужно добавить:

```
command: ['/path_to_bash_script/entrypoint.sh']
```

для запуска этого скрипта, при сборке контейнера.

Comment: вместо паузы наверное есть вариант по лучше

Comment: Вау... большое спасибо Не додумался бы до такого)